# bootstrap-tables showing undefindedText-Option instead of json data

Tags: json, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with bootstrap-table and table data from url.
Thats my html-code:

```
<table data-toggle="table"
    data-url="/framework/21/?action=tabledata&cid=1"
    data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data_field="staff_nr">staff_nr</th>
            <th data_field="staff_name">staff_name</th>
            <th data_field="staff_surname">staff_surname</th>
            <th data_field="valid">valid</th>
            <th data_field="valid_till">valid_till</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The create JSON looks like this:

```
[ { "id": 25, "staff_nr": "1", "staff_name": "Jackson", "staff_surname": "Michael", "valid": "01.02.2014", "valid_till": "28.03.2014" } ]
```

The table is created, but instead of displaying the json values only a "-" (which is the undefindedText-Option) is displayed in all columns.

Result:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| staff_nr        | staff_name         | staff_surname     |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| -               | -                  | -                 |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am working with django, but I guess it's not important for my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `data_field` instead of `data-field`

```
<tr>
     <th data-field="id">ID</th>
     <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
     <th data-field="staff_nr">staff_nr</th>
     <th data-field="staff_name">staff_name</th>
     <th data-field="staff_surname">staff_surname</th>
     <th data-field="valid">valid</th>
     <th data-field="valid_till">valid_till</th>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/740/)

Comment: oh my god... What a stupid mistake
Thank you so much!